# What's my singing skill level?

Tags: voice

https://voca.ro/jgoI1l8TK38
https://voca.ro/8f4GqHAL4Jj
https://voca.ro/9g02naEp6DC
https://voca.ro/bHDALS7IxYP

1. I would like to know if I am almost on tune or completely out of tune...
   Thanks in advance
2. How to know by myself if the recording of the singing is on tune or almost if the song does not have a solfeggio musical staff ?

Comment: That's not what I'd call 'singing' at all, it's just mumbling. I hear no recognisable tuning centre at all.

Comment: what is a tuning centre ?

Comment: At simplest, a 'start note' that everything else works from. A relative guide to follow [with either external pitch reference or just in your own head] in order to determine you are hitting the right note each time.

Comment: Not knowing what the tune was supposed to be , there's no way of telling anything. What you sang could be anything - or nothing. Your question needs a lot more clarity - as does the recording.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is some room for improvement ;)

To recognize if you sing in tune or not you need *ear training*. This is a practice of recognizing intervals and chords and ability to repeat them. Typically every student of a music school attends ear training classes. A musician can then immediately recognize if they are in tune or not.

But even more importantly you obviously lack proper vocal technique. Novice singers often think they can't sing in tune because they have "bad ears", while in fact they need better singing technique, primarily better breath support.

The best advice I can give to you is to either go to a music school, or find a vocal teacher. Perhaps singing lessons by itself can give you enough ear training to get your singing to the level you're aiming for.